# What is the right approach to use Firebase Authentication from a command line utility?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth, command-line-interface

We have a (developers oriented) web app, which uses Firebase Authentication (one-time email links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth). Currently we are about to introduce a command line utility using the same API as the web app. Obviously we'd like to re-use the same authentication mechanism in the command line utility. Ultimately we just need to store access and refresh tokens on the file system making them available to the command like utility for later use (somewhere like at `~/.mycli.config`).

We are able to send authentication emails using https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri and https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode endpoints. However it's not clear what approach to take for completion of authentication.

Shall we simply add `localhost` in the list of authorised domains and redirect authenticated users to the local web server running while the command line utility handles authentication?

Is it too insecure? If I understand correctly `gcloud auth login` works similarly.

What are other options?